# Skype keeps microphone open after call ends

Tags: security, skype, microphone

After a call ends, Skype (8.60.0.76) for Linux keeps the microphone open on my Linux (Ubuntu 20.04) machine. This is visible by the icons in the status bar

[image]

(the microphone icon disappears as soon as I quit Skype) and can be confirmed by running `pavucontrol`

[image]

Is this normal behavior? Should I be worried? Should I uninstall Skype and reinstall it?

Comment: I am seeing the same in Ubuntu KDE and was wondering whether it is just a widget bug or skype indeed keeps on listening to you

Answer (score 1):

Quick update: I confirm that the behavior persists after every Skype call, even after updating Skype with the signed package from Microsoft (which should remove the package and reinstall it).

I asked the same question on [Microsoft Answers](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/all/skype-for-linux-keeps-microphone-open-after-call/bc9865e6-16c9-455f-b605-14b71d94fd6f), where it got a useless answer by a "Microsoft Agent" after 3 weeks and was locked shortly after, before I even noticed the answer, so I did not have the occasion to reply. 5 people clicked on "I have the same question" though.

TL;DR: sketchy microphone handling under Skype for Linux confirmed. Microsoft dodges the question.

Comment: Found something but rather unconclusive: https://www.reddit.com/r/skype/comments/9iv8vd/why_does_skype_access_the_microphone_while_you/

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a display bug and skype is not using the microphone afterwards.

I have run this command during skype call:

`lsof | grep '/dev/snd'` to see whether any microphone is used.

And found something like:

```
pulseaudi  1453                             vlad  mem       CHR              116,4                  555 /dev/snd/pcmC1D8p
pulseaudi  1453                             vlad   18u      CHR             116,10       0t0        565 /dev/snd/controlC1
pulseaudi  1453                             vlad   23u      CHR             116,10       0t0        565 /dev/snd/controlC1
pulseaudi  1453                             vlad   24u      CHR             116,15       0t0        591 /dev/snd/controlC0
pulseaudi  1453                             vlad   29u      CHR             116,17       0t0        671 /dev/snd/controlC2
pulseaudi  1453                             vlad   37u      CHR             116,15       0t0        591 /dev/snd/controlC0
pulseaudi  1453                             vlad   58u      CHR             116,10       0t0        565 /dev/snd/controlC1
pulseaudi  1453                             vlad   64u      CHR              116,4       0t0        555 /dev/snd/pcmC1D8p
pulseaudi  1453  1553 alsa-sink             vlad  mem       CHR              116,4                  555 /dev/snd/pcmC1D8p
```

It looks like my microphone is:

`/dev/snd/pcmC1D8p`

Then I finished the call (but kept skype opened - with the tray icon saying that skype is using the microphone) and ran the command again:

`lsof | grep '/dev/snd'`

This time the output contained only `control` entries.

```
pulseaudi  1453                             vlad   18u      CHR             116,10       0t0        565 /dev/snd/controlC1
pulseaudi  1453                             vlad   23u      CHR             116,10       0t0        565 /dev/snd/controlC1
pulseaudi  1453                             vlad   24u      CHR             116,15       0t0        591 /dev/snd/controlC0
pulseaudi  1453                             vlad   29u      CHR             116,17       0t0        671 /dev/snd/controlC2
pulseaudi  1453                             vlad   37u      CHR             116,15       0t0        591 /dev/snd/controlC0
pulseaudi  1453  1553 alsa-sink             vlad   18u      CHR             116,10       0t0        565 /dev/snd/controlC1
```

I then closed skype completely and ran that command again. The output was identical with previous:

```
pulseaudi  1453                             vlad   18u      CHR             116,10       0t0        565 /dev/snd/controlC1
pulseaudi  1453                             vlad   23u      CHR             116,10       0t0        565 /dev/snd/controlC1
pulseaudi  1453                             vlad   24u      CHR             116,15       0t0        591 /dev/snd/controlC0
pulseaudi  1453                             vlad   29u      CHR             116,17       0t0        671 /dev/snd/controlC2
pulseaudi  1453                             vlad   37u      CHR             116,15       0t0        591 /dev/snd/controlC0
pulseaudi  1453  1553 alsa-sink             vlad   18u      CHR             116,10       0t0        565 /dev/snd/controlC1
```

Comment: Apparently files ending in `p` are playback devices, not capture devices https://alsa.opensrc.org/Proc_asound_documentation . Also, I am not really sure that those files tell all the story.

Comment: I am not an expert in this area, but there is at least some trace of Skype being connected to Pulseaudio after a call ends, as can be confirmed by running `pactl list clients | grep Skype`. Not sure what it entails, though.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, indeed, ending in `p` means playback. However, I didn't paste the whole output because it was big. I also had this `pulseaudi  1453                             vlad  mem       CHR             116,16                  670 /dev/snd/pcmC2D0c`  - with c - which must be the microphone.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni indeed, `pactl list clients` shows Skype, but it doesn't mean the microphone is being used. As you can see in that list, there is also Firefox, Chrome, ... all apps which registered themselves as users of microphone. As manual for `pactl` says - `list [short] [TYPE]  Dump all currently loaded modules, available sinks, sources, streams, etc. `